# Expect script not working

Tags: unix, expect

Below is my script where I am trying to login to a new server:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn ssh root@new_server

expect {

"*(yes/no)?" {send "yes\r"}

"*?assword:" {send "9a9c704a2fb0f9c9\r"}

"*current*" {send "9a9c704a2fb0f9c9\r"}

"Enter*" {send "Jan2016\r"}

"Retype*" {send "Jan2016\r"}

}
```

But it is exiting like this:

```
**mayankp@mayankp:~/scripts/new$** ./connect-to-server.sh_1

spawn ssh root@new_server

The authenticity of host 'new_server (new_server)' can't be established.

ECDSA key fingerprint is f4:5d:54:14:6c:e3:88:b5:eb:1f:39:bd:34:f6:64:9d.

Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? mayankp@mayankp:~/scripts/new$
```

Can someone let me know where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `exp_continue`, which will make the `Expect` to run again.

```
!/usr/bin/expect

spawn ssh root@new_server

expect {

    "*(yes/no)?" {send "yes\r";exp_continue}

    "*?assword:" {send "9a9c704a2fb0f9c9\r";exp_continue}

    "current" {send "9a9c704a2fb0f9c9\r";exp_continue}

    "Enter*" {send "Jan2016\r";exp_continue}

    "Retype*" {send "Jan2016\r";exp_continue}

    "\\\$"  { puts "matched prompt"}

}
```